# iOS 7 - Detect physical knock/hard clap (NOT shake)

Tags: ios, core-motion, motion

I'm trying to detect a knock (i.e. on the back of the phone) via the accelerometer. I'va only been able to find this code, but most of it is deprecated in iOS 7, and I can't figure out how to "re-code" it.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
#define kUpdateFrequency    100.0
#define kFilteringFactor    0.1
float accelZ;
int spikeZCount = 0; 

[[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setUpdateInterval:1.0 / kUpdateFrequency];
[[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:self];

- (void) accelerometer: (UIAccelerometer *) accelerometer didAccelerate: (UIAcceleration *) acceleration {
accelZ = acceleration.z - ( (acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor) + (accelZ * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)) );

    if (accelZ > 0.0f) {
        if (spikeZCount > 9) {
            //  NSLog(@"SPIKE!");
            [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:nil];

            [self isBumped];
        }
        else {
            spikeZCount++;
            //  NSLog(@"spikeZCount %i",spikeZCount);
        }
    }
    else {
        // NSLog(@"spikeZCount Reset");
        spikeZCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Thanks!